# Roteamento Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, router

Sou novo no uso Express JS e gostaria de fazer um direcionamento de acordo com a sessão criada, ou seja, de acordo com o perfil do usuário, a aplicação possui um rota inicial "auditoria" e terá 2 perfils de usuários e quero que o express chame o arquivo de rota correspondente ao perfil, basicamente seria mais ou menos assim:

```
var routerAdmin_1 = require('./routes/admin_1');
var routerAdmin_2 = require('./routes/admin_2');

app.use('/auditoria', (req, res, next) => {
  if(req.session.cargo == 'ADMIN_1'){
    chamar routerAdmin_1 
  }else if(req.session.cargo == 'ADMIN_2'){
    chamar routerAdmin_2 
  }else{
    console.log('Acesso negado')
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifiquei seu código, como segue:

```js
var routerAdmin_1 = require('./routes/admin_1');
var routerAdmin_2 = require('./routes/admin_2');

app.use('/auditoria', (req, res, next) => {
  if(req.session.cargo == 'ADMIN_1'){
    res.redirect(routerAdmin_1caminho) 
  }else if(req.session.cargo == 'ADMIN_2'){
    res.redirect(routerAdmin_2caminho)
  }else{
    console.log('Acesso negado')
  }

});
```

Agora, apenas substitua `routerAdmin_1caminho` e `routerAdmin_2caminho` pelos seus respectivos endereços.

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Segundo a documentação do express você pode utilizar o metodo redirect

ex

```
app.use('/route', (req, res) => {
  if (condicao) {
    res.redirect('/admin')
  }
})
```

https://expressjs.com/pt-br/4x/api.html#res.redirect